# Does the specified child already have a parent?

Tags: android, android-view

**Code:**

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(View view, int position) {

    View myView = views.get(position);
    myView.invalidate();

    ((ViewPager) view).removeView(myView);

    ((ViewPager) view).addView(myView); //Causing Error
    return myView;
}
```

**Error Log:**

```
com.testapp.main fatal error : The specified child already has a parent. 
You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. 
You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3378)
at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3249)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addView(ViewPager.java:1243)
at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3194)
at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3170)
```

I called `removeView()` before adding the child view then why the error ?

Comment: I would try using `myView.getParent().removeView(myView);` instead. See if that works. Also, are you aware that you are accessing `view` and `views`, which seem to be two different objects?

Comment: The parent of myView doesn't have removeView method as its parent is not a view. This is created dynamically as `ArrayList<LinearLayout> views = new ArrayList<LinearLayout>(); views.add(layout)` where layout is a LinearLayout created dynamically too.